# Cannot read property 'list' of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using this method to query if the calculated distance is lesser than the limit. Then it will execute this query method passing back to request.html page. Or is there any other way to execute the query if only the calculated distance is lesser than the limit then it will do the query passing back to request.html page.

```
this.getRequest = this.angFire.list('request', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'reqdetails',
        startAt: 'reqdetails'
      }
    })
```

I am getting this error:

[image]

My openMapPage() method:

```
     openMapPage()
      { 

        // GETTING THE CURRENT USER ADDRESS FOR LATITUDE AND LONGTITUDE
        var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        var ref = firebase.database().ref("request/" + uid);
        ref.once("value").then((snapshot) => { // <------ Here!
            var a = snapshot.exists();  // true
            var c = snapshot.hasChild("reqdetails"); // true
            var d = snapshot.child('reqdetails').exists();
            var requestsKey = snapshot.key;
            var requestsValue = snapshot.val();


           ref.once('value', (request) => {
      var currentUserAddress = request.val().regdetails.address;
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': currentUserAddress}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
          var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
          this.latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
          //console.log("HAHAH current user");
          //var meterLimit  = this.latlng;
          //var userAddress = new LatLng(currentUserAddress);
          //console.log("SURESH IS COOL");
        } 
      }); 

    });           

    //END OF CURRENT USER 
    }); 


      // GETTING THE ALL  USER ADDRESS FOR LATITUDE AND LONGTITUDE
        var ref1 = firebase.database().ref("request");
        ref1.once("value").then((snapshot1) => { // <------ Here!
            var a = snapshot1.exists();  // true
            var c = snapshot1.hasChild("reqdetails"); // true
            var d = snapshot1.child('reqdetails').exists();
            var requestsKey = snapshot1.key;
            var requestsValue = snapshot1.val();


            snapshot1.forEach((childSnapshot) => { // <------ And here!
                var requestKey = childSnapshot.key;
                var requestValue = childSnapshot.val();
                var reqdetails = requestValue.reqdetails;
                var AllUserAddress = requestValue.regdetails.address;




            var geocoder1 = new google.maps.Geocoder();

      geocoder1.geocode( { 'address': AllUserAddress}, function(results, status) {
        var limit = 10;
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          var latitude1 = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
          var longitude1 = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
          this.latlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude1, longitude1);
          //var userAddress = new LatLng(currentUserAddress);
           //console.log(latlng1);
           var dist: number = parseInt((google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(this.latlng,this.latlng1) / 1000).toFixed(2));



           if(dist < limit)
           {
             console.log(dist);
             console.log(AllUserAddress);  

             this.getRequest = this.angFire.list('request', {
          query: {
            orderByChild: 'reqdetails',
            startAt: 'reqdetails'
          }
        })

           }


        } 
      }); 





            });


    });

  }
```

My request.html page

[image]

My constructor:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private angFire: AngularFireDatabase,private af: AngularFireDatabase,
  private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {


  }
```

Comment: What is this.angFire?

Comment: See my updated post.

Comment: @Suresh check if `this` really refers to your class. You are in a callback function so my  guess is that `this` refers to that function, which will explain why `angFire` is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your constructor, `angFire` should exist on your class. That means that the only explanation is that `this` does not refer to your class.

Looking at your code where the error is thrown, it is encapsulated in a callback function where you do not use the typescript notations. If you declare your callback function linq-like, you'll probably get the correct reference to your class:

```
// change this:
geocoder1.geocode( { 'address': AllUserAddress}, function(results, status) {
    // 'this' references the callback function

// to this:
geocoder1.geocode( { 'address': AllUserAddress}, (results, status) => {
    // 'this' now references the class
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `this` keyword directly into code. Try to use this line top of the method

```
var self = this;
```

use this line anywhere

```
self.getRequest = self.angFire.list
```

Comment: your question is not clear, can you provide a plunker or fiddle?